# Polymerfire - creating data after an event

Tags: polymer, firebase-polymer

I'm using the firebase/polymerfire package from bower *bower install firebase/polymerfire*

how can i create some data in the database after a method has been triggered?

The document tag looks like it will display and update data. I would like to, when a user signs up, create some data for the user to use.

```
app.signInAnonymously = function() {
        this.error = null;
        this.$.auth.signInAnonymously();
        // add default data for the user template
      };
```

How can i use the default set() or push methods like the normal SDK?

How can i call this on an event from JavaScript?

When trying to bind a path to my document like

```
<firebase-document
 path="/"
 data="{{firebaseData}}">
</firebase-document>


 {{firebaseData}}
```

the data won't display, but I have authentication working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually use the firebase api directly there since `firebase-auth` is already including it, but if you want to keep the element-based functionality you could do this:

Add an empty `firebase-document` to your `template`

```
<firebase-document id="mydoc"></firebase-document>
```

Then call its `save` function in your element

```
app.signInAnonymously = function() {
    this.error = null;
    this.$.auth.signInAnonymously();
    // add default data for the user template

    //set path to null somewhere to avoid overwriting data, I recommend doing it here since save's path update is lazy
    this.$.mydoc.path = null;

    //set data to the value to set/push
    this.$.mydoc.data = {/*your data*/};

    //call save, if the second parameter is falsey it'll call push to the first parameter if it's truthy it'll set the data to firstparam/secondparam
    this.$.mydoc.save('path/to/users', userid);
  };
```

As for getting data with `firebase-document`, check that you actually have data in your database and your security rules, if you still can't see your data then it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/issues/18), do bear in mind that `polymerfire` is still in a pre-release state

Comment: How can I use the firebase.auth and firebase.database directly?

Comment: I guess you mean how to use the js api directly, in which case you should go check out the [various](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) [tutorials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) [they have](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start), then again, if you're already using polymer you might as well wait until polymerfire is properly released as it's somewhat easier to use

Comment: This feels a bit strange since my `firebase-document` already has a path specified. Seems like it should have an `.addChild()` method or something along those lines.